# RESTful Domain Application Protocol for an order

Tags: rest, api-design, restful-url

I'm working a little project. This is the first time I'm using a restful service. I'm creating a webshop and an app which are using a restful service. I created a DAP for ordering clothes in the webshop.

DAP:
[image]

State transitions in het DAP:

[image]

I want to know if I made a correct DAP, if the URI Tunnelling is correct and if the state transitions are right.

Thankyou for your help!

Edit: the first POST must be /order not order/1

Comment: Is first post creating a new order? The URI /order/1 exists previously to the creation of the entity?

Comment: Oh my fault. It has to be /order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem most people make when starting out with restful services is thinking that everything applies to one resource, in your case order.

In fact you are working with 3 resources, `orders`, `payments` and `deliveries` - when you realize this then your options suddenly expand.

Now you could do something like this:

```
POST /order  (creates order, returns Order Id)
POST /order/{OrderId}/cancel (updates order to cancelled **)
POST /order/{OrderId}/payments (creates a payment for Order, returns Payment Id ***)
POST /payments/{PaymentId}/deliveries (creates a delivery for a Payment, returns Delivery Id ***)
```

** This is a debatable point in RESTful design, could be a PUT as well, the choice is ultimately yours. [there is a ton of discussions on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest)
*** This makes sense because you would only create a Payment or Delivery in relation to another resource

Then you could access or modify the additional resources as such:

```
GET /payments
GET /payments/{PaymentId}
DELETE /payments/{PaymentId}
PUT /payments/{PaymentId}

GET /deliveries
GET /deliveries/{DeliveryId}
DELETE /deliveries/{DeliveryId}
PUT /deliveries/{DeliveryId}
```

Hope this gives you some more ideas.